# Cannot click a/button in front of img in IE6 or IE9

Tags: html, css

## Problem

I am writing a web page where the user can **click on part of an image to trigger a Javascript event**. However, I found out that if I put an absolutely-positioned **anchor**(`a`) / **button**(`input type=button`) on an **image**(`img`), the user cannot click it in **IE** (only), even if it is on top of the image.

## Demo

```
<style type="text/css">
.MyDiv
{
    position:relative;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    width:275px;
    height:95px;
}

.MyDiv .MyImageDiv
{
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    width:275px;
    height:95px;
    background-image:url('https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png');
}

.MyDiv .MyButton
{
    position:absolute;
    left:162px;
    top:20px;
    width:53px;
    height:80px;

    display:inline-block;    /* Added based on @Zeta's comment */

    background-color:transparent;
/*    background-color:black;opacity:0.5;*/
    border:0px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
</style>

<!-- Button on image: cannot click in IE. Why? -->
<div class='MyDiv'>
    <img src='https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png' />
    <input type='button' class='MyButton' onClick="alert('You clicked g!');"/>
</div>

<!-- Anchor on image: cannot click in IE. Why? -->
<div class='MyDiv'>
    <img src='https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png' />
    <a href='#' class='MyButton' onClick="alert('You clicked g!');"></a>
</div>

<hr/>

<!-- Button on div with background-image: no problem -->
<div class='MyDiv'>
    <div class='MyImageDiv'></div>
    <input type='button' class='MyButton' onClick="alert('You clicked g!');"/>
</div>

<!-- Anchor on div with background-image: no problem -->
<div class='MyDiv'>
    <div class='MyImageDiv'></div>
    <a href='#' class='MyButton' onClick="alert('You clicked g!');"></a>
</div>
```

## Live Demo

To test, click on small letter **g** in

- [Demo1](http://pang.phpfogapp.com/stackoverflow/10849511/demo.php) (original)
- [Demo2](http://pang.phpfogapp.com/stackoverflow/10849511/demo_w3c_validated.php) (full, w3c validated)
- [Demo3](http://pang.phpfogapp.com/stackoverflow/10849511/demo_w3c_validated_with_text_indent.php) (full, w3c validated, with `text-indent` as suggested by @Sparky672).

EDIT (2012-12-05): Migrated demos to jsfiddle.

- [Demo4@jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XGcG5/1/)
- [Demo5@jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XGcG5/2/) (with `text-indent` as suggested by @Sparky672).

## Details

I can click and trigger the bottom two alerts in all browsers; however, **the first two *CANNOT* be triggered in IE** (see test results below). It is ok because I can always remind myself not to write in that way, but is there a sensible explanation as for why this is happening?

P.S. I tried using `z-index` on the anchor / button, but it didn't help.

EDIT (2012-06-01): Tried using `display:block` / `display:inline-block` on the anchor / button (as per @Zeta's comment), but it didn't help.

I also tried using IE9's Developer Tools (F12) to try to debug the page. If I use the arrow tool (Ctrl+B) to select the anchor / button, it cannot be selected; but if I highlight the anchor / button element in the HTML of the Developer Tools, it correctly shows the position and size of the anchor / button. Strange enough.

## Test results

```
+-------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
|                                                       | Can click on anchor / button on image |
+-------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| IE 6.0.2900.2180.xpsp_sp2_gdr.100216-1441, on Windows | **NO**                                |
| IE 9.0.8112.16421, on Windows                         | **NO**                                |
| Opera 11.64, on Windows                               | Yes                                   |
| Opera 12.00, on Windows                               | Yes                                   |
| Opera 12.02, on Windows                               | Yes                                   |
| Opera 12.11, on Windows                               | Yes                                   |
| Opera 11.64, on Mac                                   | Yes                                   |
| Opera 12.00, on Mac                                   | Yes                                   |
| Opera Mini 7.0.4, on iPhone                           | Yes                                   |
| Firefox 12.0, on Windows                              | Yes                                   |
| Firefox 14.0.1, on Windows                            | Yes                                   |
| Firefox 15.0.1, on Windows                            | Yes                                   |
| Firefox 13.0, on Mac                                  | Yes                                   |
| Chrome 19.0.1084.52m, on Windows                      | Yes                                   |
| Chrome 22.0.1229.79 m, on Windows                     | Yes                                   |
| Chrome 23.0.1271.95 m, on Windows                     | Yes                                   |
| Chrome 19.0.1084.54, on Mac                           | Yes                                   |
| Chrome 21.0.1180.82, on iPhone                        | Yes                                   |
| Safari 5.1.5, on Windows                              | Yes                                   |
| Safari 5.1.7 (7534.57.2), on Windows                  | Yes                                   |
| Safari 5.1.7 (7534.57.2), on Mac                      | Yes                                   |
| Safari, on iOS 4.3.5                                  | Yes                                   |
| Browser, on Android 3.1                               | Yes                                   |
+-------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Have you tried using `display:block` on `.MyButton`?

Comment: @Zeta Tried display:block and display:inline-block. No help.

Comment: Does the HTML validate with the [W3C Validation tool](http://validator.w3.org/)?  IE is **very** fussy about invalid HTML.

Comment: The anchor tag is totally empty.  `<a>` is an inline element so I don't see how it's going to have any size without any content.  Zeta's comment should help towards fixing that.  However, for IE, you also need to put text inside of it and then hide the text with a large negative `text-indent`.

Comment: @Sparky672 Tried adding some text inside `<a>` and set a negative `text-indent`. `<a>` is still unclickable as long as it is on top of an `<img>` (in **IE** only).

Comment: I have no idea why it doesn't work for you.  I use that method frequently and it works for me in all versions of IE.

Comment: @Sparky672 Added W3C-validated live demos, even one with `text-indent` [here](http://pang.phpfogapp.com/stackoverflow/10849511/demo_w3c_validated_with_text_indent.php). Still can't click on anchor / button on top of image in my **IE9**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Conclusion

Here's my conclusion after a lot more research.

In [this page](http://nopeople.com/CSS%20tips/empty_anchor/index.html), the author experienced the **same behaviour in IE8**.

In this SO question ([1663919](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663919/how-to-make-an-empty-anchor-tag-clickable-in-ie7)), the author experienced the **same behaviour in IE7**.

In these SO questions ([1075684](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075684/ie-only-part-of-an-anchor-is-clickable), [4639921](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639921/clicking-on-a-div-placed-over-an-image-in-ie)), the authors have the **same problems in IE in** slightly different but **similar scenarios**.

It seems that [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html) does not mention anything about that, but since it only happens in IE and it only happens when the anchor / button is put on top of an image (which isn't quite anyone would expect), I would say this is just a bug in IE.

## Workarounds

Use *any one* below to workaround the problem:

1. Do not put an anchor / button on an image. Instead, put it on a `div` with a CSS `background-image` (as stated in the Question).
2. Set the following CSS property **on the anchor / button**, which makes it clickable again in IE (as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1664014/1402846)).

   ```
   background-image:url(about:blank)
   ```

Comment: Tried option 2 and worked, much less intrusive as no need to recode any elements...

Comment: The 2nd option worked for me. Was experiencing this behavior in IE9 compatibility mode (Windows 10).

Answer (score 1):

There is one thing that is confusing here

On the first two divs you use img before either input or a tags

```
<div class='MyDiv'>
    <img src='https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png' />
    <input type='button' class='MyButton' onClick="alert('You clicked g!');"/>
</div>

<div class='MyDiv'>
    <img src='https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png' />
    <a href='#' class='MyButton' onClick="alert('You clicked g!');"/></a>
</div>
```

On the other divs, it's just divs before the inputs. Any reason for this?

Try this putting the img inside the a tag.

```
<div class='MyDiv'>
    <a href='#' class='MyButton' onClick="alert('You clicked g!');"/><img src='https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png' /></a>

</div>

<div class='MyDiv'>

    <a href='#' class='MyButton' onClick="alert('You clicked g!');"/><img src='https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png' /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: It's because I want to make part of (not the whole) image clickable.
For the last two divs, it's just divs with background-image set in CSS, so both sets of divs look exactly the same.